# Macro to move Column to new sheet moves only last column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move selected columns by header name to a new page pasting into consecutive columns starting at column `A`

My Macro is only moving the last column

Thanks

```
Sub MoveColumnsToNewSheet()
Dim ar As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim LR As Long

Sheets(1).Select

    ar = Array("user name", "Label")     ' Find column to copy

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
    j = Rows(1).Find(ar(i), Rows(1).Cells(Rows(1).Cells.Count), , xlWhole, xlByRows).Column

      Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(LR, j)).Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets(2).Columns(i)
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the `LBound` of a `Variant` array will be 0, so `Columns(i)` will fail on the first loop. I think that rather than "only moving the last column" it wasn't moving the first - a subtle distinction with only two columns.

This would have been easier to spot if your `On Error` statements spanned less code. You only need it for the `Find` statement.

Also note that you need to reset `j` to 0 each time and then check if something was found by testing if it's still 0.

Finally, please qualify all ranges, rows, etc., with worksheet names. I did that here using a `With` statement to make it less repetitive:

```
Sub MoveColumnsToNewSheet()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ar As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim LR As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
ar = Array("user name", "Label")     ' Find column to copy

With wsSource
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
        On Error Resume Next
        j = 0
        j = .Rows(1).Find(ar(i), .Rows(1).Cells(.Rows(1).Cells.Count), , xlWhole, xlByRows).Column
        On Error GoTo 0
        If j <> 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(LR, j)).Copy _
                    Destination:=wsTarget.Columns(i + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

And finally, finally, I'd encourage more meaningful variable names than `ar`. When this code grows and time passes you'll be saying "ar of what?!"

Comment: Thanks for the fix on my macro, equally thanks for the great commentary